# Any open source Spring blog project or forum project?

Tags: java, spring, blogs, forum

I learn spring for some time. now I want to read some open source project code which is about blog or forum, then I will use spring to build my own blog project in practice.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5818259/1130032
2. http://seantheflexguy.com/blog/2009/02/25/simple-spring-example-project/

Comment: @Felix stackoverflow provides the facility to accept the answer if you know..!!